# Reading user-input in the same line as the script execution

Tags: bash, shell

I have a BASH script named fib.sh. The script reads a user input (number) and performs a calculation. I want to be able to type

```
$ ./fib.sh 8
```

where 8 is the input

Currently, I have to wait for the next line to enter the input.

```
$ ./fib.sh 
$ 8
```

Script

```
#!/bin/bash

read n

a=0
b=1
count=1
fib=$a

while [ $count -lt $n ]; 
do
    fib=$[$a+$b]
    a=$b
    b=$fib
    count=$[$count+1]
done

echo "fib $n = $fib"

exit 0
```

Comment: `$[…]` is deprecated; use `$((…))` (part of the POSIX standard) instead. Example `fib=$(($a+$b))`.

Comment: @chepner you don't even need the `$` inside: `$((a+b))`.

Comment: True; I was just trying to move the code off the deprecated syntax first; using it to its full capabilities can come later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to pass a parameter to the script instead of reading it. In this case, use `$1` as shown here:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=$1 <---- this will take from the call of the script
echo "I have been given the parameter $n"

a=0
b=1
count=1
fib=$a

while [ $count -lt $n ]; 
do
    fib=$[$a+$b]
    a=$b
    b=$fib
    count=$[$count+1]
done

echo "fib $n = $fib"

exit 0
```